# How to make api call and populate in render in react function based view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const App  = () => {
  const [setData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.com/users/')
    .then(res => res.hson())
    .then(res => {
      setData(res);
    })
  });

  return ({
    setData.map(data => {
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
    })
  });
}
```

Here I am making an api call in react using functional component.
It is coming the result.

But I am not able to populate result in render.
Showing map is not a function error.

Please have a look.

Comment: Please show us the full error

Comment: I think you need to initialise the state with empty array rather than an empty string. Also please check if the response is an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const App  = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.com/users/`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      setData(res);
    })
  }, []);

  return !!data && data.map(data => <h1>{data.name}</h1>);
}
```

First use an array as the default value for your state

Use the data variable to loop over the results

The useState hook returns 2 values, the data and the function to change that data